# How to use youtube playerview with scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, youtube-api

When i use youtube playerview with Scrollview. i get following error:

```
05-17 16:39:16.899 28246-28246/com.example.mgic.projectmovie E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.mgic.projectmovie, PID: 28246
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mgic.projectmovie/com.example.mgic.projectmovie.Video}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.mgic.projectmovie.Video.onCreate(Video.java:64)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2188)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

following is my layout:

```
  <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_80sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_55sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_30sdp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: What is `Logcat` showing. Post your Logcat.

Comment: The error is here ` com.example.mgic.projectmovie.Video.onCreate(Video.java:64)`. what is in this line ?

Answer (score 2):

Youtube player view does not play a video if any other layout is drawn over it. Hence if you are using it inside a scroll view, it's assured it will not play and throw a overlay error log. The approach to be considered in this scenario is to show a thumbnail of the video in the Scroll view, on clicking the thumbnail navigate the user to a new standalone layout that contains only the player view and play the video there.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get a `YouTubePlayerFragment` to work within a `NestedScrollView`. the short answer is that i have a root-level layout (floating container) which tracks the position of an `ImageView` (video thumbnail), inside the `NestedScrollView`. when i want to load the player, the fragment manager adds it to the root-level layout. the player will continue to play, unless it's scrolled offscreen, and an overlay is detected.

some code:

```
...
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/topic_modules_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/topic_modules"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/topic_youtube_floating_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
...
```

then add the scroll change logic

```
        final DetailYouTubeVideoFragment ytf = CustomYouTubeVideoFragment.newInstance(object, null);

        mNestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                final View fragmentView = ytf.getView();
                if (fragmentView != null) {
                    final int sY = v.getScrollY(),
                            top = fragmentView.getTop() + v.getPaddingBottom(),
                            newTop = top - sY;

                    mYoutubeFloatingLayout.setTop(newTop);
                    mYoutubeFloatingLayout.setBottom(newTop + fragmentView.getHeight());
                }
            }
        });

        mYoutubeFloatingLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                // prevent repositioning when player state changes
                if (top != oldTop) {
                    mYoutubeFloatingLayout.setTop(oldTop);
                    mYoutubeFloatingLayout.setBottom(oldBottom);
                }
            }
        });
```

my `DetailYouTubeVideoFragment` has a field to a `YouTubePlayerFragment`. within my fragment, the player fragment is inserted into the floating container...

```
getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.topic_youtube_floating_fragment_container, mYouTubePlayerFragment)
            .commit();
```

while this worked for my app, it might not work for every case. good luck!